# How do I prove the correctness of this isomorphism relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I want to show that $$[m] \uplus [n] \cong [m+n]$$ but I don't get why this is true. I see that $[m] = \{0, 1, 2, ... m-1\}$ and $[n] = \{0, 1, 2, ... n-1\}$but I don't see how this could lead to $[m+n] = \{0, 1, .... m+n-1\}$. Why is this even true?

---

The same goes for a relationship like $[m] \times [n] \cong [m\cdot n]$ (as a side note, why must it be $\times$ and not a multiplication for this relation? Or is this isomorphism incorrect?

Comment: I don't even know what in the world this means.

Comment: Let $m=n$. What is the group operation on the union?

Comment: @AndresMejia I believe it might be because my text uses an extremely old notation but I have no idea what are the new ones. To explain, $\uplus$ is the disjoint union. $[m]$ is an example equivalence relation that consist of elements from 0 to $m-1$ when mod $m$.

Answer (score 0):

This is only going to work if your symbol $\uplus$ refers to the *disjoint union*, not just the union. There's several ways to instantiate the disjoint union, with one of the easiest being:

$A \uplus B = (A \times \{0\}) \cup (B \times \{1\})$

This ensures that the elements coming from $A$ and the elements coming from $B$ don't coincide. See if you can make it work with that definition.

*Comment*: These relations are basically about reflecting the usual operations on the natural numbers in the context of the cardinalities of finite sets. The disjoint union of sets corresponds to addition and the Cartesian product of sets corresponds to multiplication.